# Angular doesn't detect changes without undefined the fields

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

Angular doesn't detect changes, and update the UI without me manually undefined the fields I want to be updated before. I don't understand why? Is that an ng bug?

```
this.dialog
  .open(this.generateKeysDialogTemplate)
  .afterClosed()
  .subscribe((keyParams) => {
    if (!keyParams) {
      return;
    }
    this.request.password = this.request.password || '';
    this.request.privateKey = undefined;
    this.request.publicKey = undefined;
    this.request.fingerprint = undefined;
    this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
    this.credentialService
      .generateKeys(this.request, keyParams.keyType, keyParams.keyLength)
      .pipe(first((x) => x !== undefined))
      .subscribe((credentialWithKey) => {
        const { credentialID, lastChangeUTC, ...properties } = credentialWithKey;
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.request = Object.assign({}, this.request, properties);
          this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
        });
      });
  });
```

as you can see I have to undefined properties in my model:

```
this.request.password = this.request.password || '';
this.request.privateKey = undefined;
this.request.publicKey = undefined;
this.request.fingerprint = undefined;
```

In order for the assigning new values update the UI with them.

```
this.request = Object.assign({}, this.request, properties);
```

It took my a long time to get this work, and I really don't like that "fix".

Adding the compoenent declaration:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mvp-credential-edit-form',
  templateUrl: './credential.detail.form.component.html',
})
export class CredentialDetailFormComponent extends FormViewBaseComponent {
  @Input()
  public request: Credential = {};
```

Comment: Can you please share the component?

Comment: Please clarify why you are using `markForCheck()` and `setTimeout()`

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I think that `setTimeout()` was added as part of trying to fix it,I'm not sure it's actually necessary. but it didn't work with or without it. and `marktForCheck()` is an attempt to tell angular that the model has changed and to update the UI. Maybe it is not necessary as well in this case..